# SharePoint Designer 2007 workflow send email extended give me no dialog box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I'm in SPD 2007. I create a new workflow and select send email extended but it does not give me the usual from and to interface.. i get nothing.  Im in a subsite. Is there a feature I need to turn on.. something I need to do the the list? normal send email seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select 'Send AN email'

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. While your answer may theoretically answer the question it is lacking in sustenance to be able to be followed as a guide. A where to go and what to do is the best way to approach answers. Please refer to the [FAQ][1] on guides to posting here. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq